# Is it possible to design a surgical (dental) implant guide in Blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I would like to know whether Blender 2.80 has a function/procedure/addon according to which a dental arch can be replicated in negative (by a predetermined offset) to design a custum impression tray or surgical guide.

I use the Boolean difference and it worked well, however, I would need a final object that has more the shape of a dental arch (rather than a cube) and of constant thickness.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know many things in the dental field, but this should put you on the right track, the answer is yes, you can model what you are looking for, but it is necessary to see exactly what you want to be able to help you improve your model

[odc_public
Addon for Blender meant to streamline dental CAD and design workflows](https://github.com/patmo141/odc_public)
[image]

but it is not in 2.8, it is in 2.79 and in addition to this there is another addon especially for the design of dental bridges, as soon as I remember the name I will provide it